# Galaxy S4 getting stuck in bootloop after random restarts

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-4, boot-loop

I have had my galaxy S4 for 4 years and the last 3 months it started to reboot randomly. After one such reboot it got stuck on the Galaxy logo in that I had assumed to be a bootloop. If I leave it off for about an hour it gets to the home screen and reboots and gets stuck again.

I have tried:

- Factory reset.
- Removing and replacing the battery.
- Flashed 3 different ROMs.

After installing a new rom the device starts up normally but after a while(at the point of setting up wifi or just seeing the home screen) it would reboot and gets stuck on the Galaxy logo. At this point the phone would heat up a little bit, nothing dangerous.

So at this point I am wondering if its a software issue or hardware.

Any suggestions on what is causing the problem or where to look for solutions would be appreciated.